# Higher Order way of getting the first element in an array that meets a condition in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Higher Order way of getting the first element in an array that meets a condition in Javascript?

suppose I have an array with these elements: `[1, 2, 3, 0, 3]`;

And I want to get the first element that is a greater than `2`.

How do you accomplish this using higher order functions?

The more compact, the better.

If I could do it on haskell, I would do:

```
head $ filter condition array
for example:
head $filter (> 2) [1, 2, 3, 0, 3]
```

Comment: What have you tried? What question do you have that is preventing you from solving this yourself?

Comment: @32bitkid I added how I would do it on another language. The problem is that I'm so new to javascript that I don't even know where to start.

Comment: @Joren Well, I'm asking something a little different by specifying that I want something that user HOF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4L8tw/)):

```
function isBigEnough(element) {
  return element >= 2;
}
alert([1, 2, 3, 0, 3].filter(isBigEnough)[0]);
```

Or the short way using an anonymous function like mentioned in the comments ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4L8tw/1/)):

```
alert([1,2,3,0,3].filter(function(e){return e>=2;})[0]);
```

[Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: "shorter is better": `[1,2,3,0,3].filter(function(e){return e>2;})[0]`

Comment: Bad idea, this will go on after finding the first matching element, where the example code in the OP will short-circuit (will not look into other elements of the array).

Answer (score 1):

underscore is a JavaScript Library with useful utility functions and includes one called find, which would do exactly what you want.

http://underscorejs.org/#find

so you could write `var x = _.find([1,2,3,0,3], function(v) { return v >= 2; });`

Comment: I like this for being the more compact, but I can't select this as the answer since it's not pure JavaScript.

Comment: @LayGonzález ahem, well it IS pure javascript. just like other frameworks like jQuery are pure javascript. You can't make javascript evaluate code that isn't valid javascript syntax! however, i will say that this isn't the "shortest" answer since you're adding a whole framework in order to do it..

Comment: @CrayonViolent you're right.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the some Array method to iterate the array until a condition is met (and then stop). Unfortunately it will only return whether the condition was met once, not by which element (or at what index) it was met.

```
function find(arr, test, ctx) {
    var result = null;
    arr.some(function(el, i) {
        return test.call(ctx, el, i, arr) ? (result = el), true : false;
    });
    return result;
}
```